# webpack error configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, loader

When I run the server using `npm run start`, I am getting following error:

```
✖ ｢wds｣: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

 - configuration has an unknown property 'debug'. These properties are valid:

   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, externals?, infrastructureLogging?, loader?, mode?, module?, name?, node?, optimization?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, serve?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }

   The 'debug' property was removed in webpack 2.0.0.

   Loaders should be updated to allow passing this option via loader options in module.rules.

   Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to switch loaders into debug mode:
   plugins: [
     new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
       debug: true
     })
   ]
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:

   object { defaultRules?, exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp? }

   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
```

My webpack.config.js is as following:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/Main.js'
  ],
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
  cache: true,
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.glsl$/,
        loader: 'webpack-glsl',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'shaders')
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      debug: true
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your webpack version ?

**As for webpack 4 - you need to change from "loaders" to "rules"**

```
module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.glsl$/, use: 'webpack-glsl' }
    ]
  ...
```

Hope this is the answer you are expecting.

Comment: my webpack version is 4.41.5, i tried as you mentioned it solves the second error but the first one remain same, can you please help me the first error 'configuration has an unknown property 'debug'. These properties are valid:'

Comment: remove the debug: true below the cache property as you have already added it the plugin section, in which their is a debug: true.    Let me know if it works and mark the answer.

Comment: @HardikPurohit coud mark the question closed if your issue is resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should change loaders to rules in webpack 4:

change `loaders`

to  `rules`  .See  [Loaders](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#example)

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/Main.js'
  ],
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },     
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
   rules: [
  { test: /\.glsl$/, use: 'webpack-glsl' }
]
  },
  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      debug: true
    })
  ]
};
```

to see debug property.See [Debug](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#debug)